# How to check out Files and create branches for TFVC repo in VS Code?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, tfvc

We want to use VS Code for source control. We want a centralized approach and created and Azure TFVC Repo and connect to it from VS Code. That worked. But now how can we checkout a File in VS Code? I know we can just edit the file and then save it and it will be automatically added to staged files. But we want really to do a check out, so that other people can see that the file is checked out and not available for changes until the other person who checked it out checked it in again. In Visual Studio this works with the action "Check out for edit" how to to that with vs code? And second how to create a new branch for a TFVC repo in vs code? I am able to create a branch from visual studio but how do I create a new branch from within code? I only see option for creating new git branch, but we have TFVC Repo.

Comment: It would be better if you would split your questions into separate questions. This makes the question+answer more searchable by future people.

Comment: @Daniel Mann could you link the questions were they were already asked/answered?